# How to authenticate in WebAPI using OAuth bearer calling style in WS-Federation?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, jwt, ws-federation, bearer-token, owin-middleware

Is there an out of the box extension for Ws-Federation authentication in OWIN middleware libraries to handle Web APIs using authentication header instead of cookies?

```
// OAuth bearer calling style
var headers = {};
headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'api/values/1',
    headers: headers
```

I know how to write a [custom handler](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/09/using-the-jwt-handler-for-implementing-poor-man-s-delegation-actas/) to extract the token and validate it but can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Visual Studio Template that comes with OAuth 2.0 server implemented as an OWIN middleware:

> New Project -> Web -> ASP.NET Application -> OK -> Web API Template, with **Individual User Accounts** authentication

Revise the `Startup.Auth.cs` file in `App_Startup` folder for auth configuration.

Comment: I have an STS using WS-Fed so I cannot use OAuth2 protocol

Answer (score 0):

I used Auth0 as Authentication Provider for one of my projects.

I did following for my Web API project.
For handling Authorization header and token, I used following Nuget Packages:

```
Install-Package WebApi.JsonWebToken
Install-Package Auth0-ASPNET
```

It adds JsonWebToken.cs and JsonWebTokenValidationHandler.cs in App_Start folder.

Opening WebApiConfig.cs add using statements

```
using projectName.App_Start;
using System.Web.Configuration;
```

and add following code snippet under Register method.

```
var clientID = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
var clientSecret = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];

config.MessageHandlers.Add(new JsonWebTokenValidationHandler()
{
    Audience = clientID,
    SymmetricKey = clientSecret
});
```

Remove anything related to Auth0 and there you have a nice handler for extracting the JWT token and also code for validating it.

Reference: https://manage.auth0.com/

Comment: I have an STS using WS-Fed so I cannot use OAuth2 protocol